# .ShowDialog() shows twice

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, duplicates, showdialog

I have an annoying problem...
I just wanted to show a dialog, but it's always showing twice... Here's the code:

```
    private void tmr_sysdt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_time.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        lbl_date.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        if (GetLastInputTime() > Program.timeout)
        {
            frm_lockscreen login= new frm_lockscreen();
            tmr_sysdt.Enabled = false;
            if (login.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) tmr_sysdt.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

The `tmr_sysdt.Interval is 1000`.

The problem is simple - but unsolvable for me - the dialog is showing in duplicate (the second is coming up AT THE SAME TIME as the first).

I have no idea, so any idea will be appreciated :)

Thank you, and if you need more details please comment!

Ps.: Sorry for bad eng

---

EDIT: GetLastInputTime()

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);
    static uint GetLastInputTime()
    {
        uint idleTime = 0;
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
        lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

        uint envTicks = (uint)Environment.TickCount;

        if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
        {
            uint lastInputTick = lastInputInfo.dwTime;

            idleTime = envTicks - lastInputTick;
        }

        return ((idleTime > 0) ? (idleTime / 1000) : 0);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwTime;
    }
```

Comment: Running GetLastInputTime + creating the screen might take you longer than 1 second?

Comment: Nope, i already tried it with 5000ms... :(

Comment: Unrelated, but are you aware that calling System.DateTime.Now on two separate lines is buggy when the date wraps right after the first line has executed? Then your form will show a time nearly 24 hours ahead. It's a unlikely but still buggy

Comment: Can you post GetLastInputTime also?

Comment: Of course, but the correct answer is going to be written now by @codemonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this code? Just to make sure the logic in your handler isn't called twice at the same time:

```
    static bool busy = false;
    private void tmr_sysdt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (busy)
        {
            return;
        }
        busy = true;
        try
        {
            lbl_time.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            lbl_date.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            if (GetLastInputTime() > Program.timeout)
            {
                frm_lockscreen login = new frm_lockscreen();
                tmr_sysdt.Enabled = false;
                if (login.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) tmr_sysdt.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            busy = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem you were having was that the code to check the last activity of the user and show the login box, was in a form that is created multiple times.
So in fact, each of these 'main forms' were checking the user activity and showing the login box.

By putting the busy bool as static, each instance of the 'main form' read this bool as the same value. Therefore, the check+show login only gets executed one time.

I would suggest moving this code to a form you only create once, and keep open during the full lifetime of the application. (If you have such a form)

Comment: Agree it's important to not trigger twice. However an much simpler approach to achieve that is having the tmr_sysdt.Enabled=false line at the beginning of the event handler and the tmr_sysdt.Enabled=true in the finally clause. That gets rid of the busy bool and related code.

Comment: I think doublehelix is going to be right, because if i'm break the first show dialog and then just pressing the F11 button, then i have only one dialog... but i am unable to understand why

Comment: Is this code on some main form in your application? Are there multiple instances of that form open? Could you try and change the `bool busy = false` to `static bool busy = false`

Comment: AND ITS WORKED! Thank you! Could you explain the problem in an answer... btw i have more form, but just one from each...

Comment: Application.Run(new frm_main()); -> frm_splashandlogin -> frm_main -> frm_lockscreen

Comment: Edited comment. i'd suggest moving this check code to a seperated class then, not in a form. You can start this check in the Program.cs before opening up the application form.

Comment: I'll do this :) Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

You want to reuse your frm_lockscreen and prevent reentry to your Tick event

```
private frm_lockscreen _lockScreen;

private frm_lockscreen LockScreen
{
    get { return _lockScreen ?? (_lockScreen = new frm_lockscreen()); }
}

private void tmr_sysdt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // prevent reentry
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(tmr_sysdt)) return;

    try {
        lbl_time.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        lbl_date.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        if (GetLastInputTime() > Program.timeout)
        {
            tmr_sysdt.Enabled = false;
            if (LockScreen.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) tmr_sysdt.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    finally {
        Monitor.Exit(tmr_sysdt);
    }
}
```

Comment: `get { _lockScreen ?? (_lockScreen = new frm_lockscreen()); }`
_Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement_

Comment: OFF: But i like this `??` operator, +1 for mentioning it! :)

Comment: not? `get {return _lockScreen ?? (_lockScreen = new frm_lockscreen()); }`

Comment: Anyhow, it's showing duplicates, so @codemonkey's answer is still the best

Comment: You're right I forgot the return. Was typing it in the iPad :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your outer if condition is returning true twice:

```
if (GetLastInputTime() > Program.timeout)
```

To find the culprit you have to check the values returned by GetLastInputTime() and Program.Timeout

Comment: I am unable to debug this, because GetLastInputTime() counts the inactivity and when i press F5 or F11 it reset... but i think this is the key of the problem somehow...